# ExtJS4.2 form.submit() 400 Status Code

Tags: extjs

1 When I used the submit method.The browser told me that is a bad request.400.
2 Here is my code.

```
if (form.isValid()) {
  form.submit({  
    submitEmptyText: false,
    method: 'post',
    url: BasePath + 'newsManage/addNews',  
    success: function(form, action) {  
      Ext.Msg.alert('操作成功', action.result.msg, function() {  
        newsPanel.getForm().reset();
        newsEditWindow.hide();  
        newsListStore.load({  
          params: formData  
        });  
      });  
    },  
    failure: function(form, action) {
      myMask.hide();
      Ext.Msg.alert('操作失败', action.result.msg);
    }  
  });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a client (Ext) problem but server problem. You may try to access http:// service via https:// protocol or vice versa, but there are [many other possible reasons.](https://www.google.sk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=u_u0VNSQNojjywPA9IKQCg#safe=off&q=bad+request)